# Not able to write into the file

Tags: java

I am trying to create a file and keep on appending into that file. In my code file is getting created but It is not appending anything in that file. Don't know why? Can anyone suggest me what wrong I am doing..

**Updated Code:-**

```
        File file =new File("D://GeoData1.txt");

    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));


    int j = -1;
    while(true) {           
        j++;
        String ipAddress = generateIPAddress(j);
        try {
            out.write(ipAddress);
            System.out.println(ipAddress);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you [closing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#close%28%29) the writer?

```
finally {
   bufferWritter.close();
}
```

**Update:**

If you are using Java 7, try this:

```
final int NUMBER_OF_IPS_TO_APPEND = 5000; // or whatever size
Charset charset = Charset.defaultCharset();
Path file = Paths.get("myfile.txt");

try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(file, charset,
                StandardOpenOption.CREATE,
                StandardOpenOption.APPEND)) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= NUMBER_OF_IPS_TO_APPEND; i++) {
        String ip = generateIPAddress(i);
        System.out.printf("Generated ip: %s\n", ip);
        writer.append(ip + "\n");
    }
} catch (IOException x) {
    System.err.format("IOException: %s\n", x);
}
```

Code adapted from [The Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html).

Check if the IPS are being printed to the console and the file.

[Fully working code](http://pastebin.com/AQgDrxa9) with a mock implementation of `generateIPAddress`. It appends 5000 random IPv4 addresses (not checking for validity) to `myfile.txt` everytime it is executed.

Comment: Nevzz03. Sorry, I meant the writer :D.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly the close() method call is not needed to see the changes in the file in this particular example. Flush do that. I have posted my own answer.

Comment: @Nevzz03 - you should not close the same writer many times - it will never work.

Comment: @hakyer, you have misinterpreted my answer.  This code is only closing the writer once to flush the remaining changes to disk and release resources. Actually, calling `flush` continually in a tight flush trashes performance and it is considered, therefore, a anti-pattern. I've never suggested to the OP, or anyone to close or flush the code inside a tight loop. The loop is inside a [try-with-resources statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) that will close the `BufferedWriter` automaticaly.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Yes - I agree with you that flushing the writer may degrade performance - but this is the only way to see the changes when you have while(true) loop (as in the code sample in this question). Of course as I suggested it can be done also by the operating system automatically.

Comment: Update to my last comment - in fact the automatic flush is done by JVM (not the OS as I said). On my Linux Box, Oracle JVM 7 the flush is taking place after every 8192 bytes written to FileWriter.

Answer (score 3):

You should close the file or flush buffers I guess.

Comment: fileWritter.flush();

Please bookmark the Java API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/

Comment: Here is the method to flush: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#flush()

Comment: @ra4king I guess he should flush `bufferWritter` for convenience.

Answer (score 1):

I would try just passing the file writer the file object and getting rid of the `.getName()`

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have infinite loop with while(true). You should make a break point with a statemant or make the the "while" loop like while(i < xy)....

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the loop is never-ending. You should at least make it stop at some point. 
Also, you need to close the file to free any memory. Hope it helps!

--edit--
To close a file, its

```
file.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the changes made to the file during the time the program is running you need to **flush** the writer. Please note that sooner or later it will be flushed automatically. The reason why you don't see changes in your text editor depends on your editor. For instance it is not able to open such big file (please note that in your program you are appending chars to this file very fast). Check the size of the file. If the size is increasing then it works.

If you want to monitor the file you can use tools like **tail**.